# What is the best way to test whether several samples come from the same set with a certainty?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, group-differences

If I have multiple multi variate samples ( consisting of large amounts of variables), how could I test whether these samples come from the same set? Also, if I group these samples in two groups, could I apply Chi-square test to tell if the groups are indistinguishable? (The samples in question are spectral data)

Comment: what do you mean by set. do you mean whether the variables were sampled from the same probability distribution?

Comment: This is a paper I’ve seen: https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/107/3/555/5856303. There’s an R package to implement the method, LPKsample. I have found this implementation to be slow, however.